# Junit/ selenium test cases

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, junit4

The password for login changes often for my application. I'm trying to use junit (selenium webdriver) to create test cases. How to automate the password changes in my Junit code, so that i don't have to make changes in the every time the password changes

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do something like this is to store the password in a DB. If you do that then you can write the code to grab the password to the db. So when the password changes then just update your db row and your tests will be fine

Comment: Thanks @jrock2004, it never occurred to me. Definitely helps!